# Asking variable outside of function

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and was wondering how I'd access $hidden outside of this function: **$(this).hide(500, function ()**

**HTML**

```
<div class="fl person"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="userSaved" value="1" /> 
    <img src="..." class="circle-mask" /> 
</div>

<div class="fl person"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="userSaved" value="2" /> 
    <img src="..." class="circle-mask" /> 
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$("div.person img").click(function () {    
    $(this).hide(500, function () {
        $(this).parent("div").empty();
        $(".main_page").appendTo("div.main_page").addClass("fl person"); 
        var saved_id_user_who_voted = $hidden = $(this).siblings('input');
    });

    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    var saved_id_user_who_voted_val = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveSavedUserToDatabase.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {saved_id_user_who_voted:saved_id_user_who_voted_val, saved_id_user_voted_on:saved_id_user_voted_on_val} 
    });
});
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to access **saved_id_user_who_voted** outside of the current function so that I can post it using .ajax - right now it's not in scope.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to your function?

Comment: remove the `var` from `saved_id_user_who_voted` in the `hide` function. Then it will use the one that is in the outer scope, instead of creating a new one within the function scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing variables from other functions without using global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407048/accessing-variables-from-other-functions-without-using-global-variables)

Comment: actually, my suggestion won't work since the `hide` function is going to be called after 500 ms (when hide completes), when the ajax will have already executed. rather, you could just move the $.ajax into the `hide` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute your AJAX request in the `hide` callback. Or declare the variable outside the `hide` callback.

```
$("div.person img").click(function () {
    $(this).hide(500, function () {
        $(this).parent("div").empty();
        $(".main_page").appendTo("div.main_page").addClass("fl person");
        var saved_id_user_who_voted = $hidden = $(this).siblings('input');

        /* attach a submit handler to the form */
        var saved_id_user_who_voted_val = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveSavedUserToDatabase.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                saved_id_user_who_voted: saved_id_user_who_voted_val,
                saved_id_user_voted_on: saved_id_user_voted_on_val
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I seem to get "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" when doing it this way.

Comment: move event.preventDefault() outside the callback

Comment: @PaulEx10 Is this answer fixed your problem or not?

Comment: I could have sworn I marked this as complete, oh well, just done it now. Thank you for your help.